# Removing 10 Characters of Filename in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, file-rename, batch-rename

I just downloaded about 600 files from my server and need to remove the last 11 characters from the filename (not including the extension). I use Ubuntu and I am searching for a command to achieve this.

Some examples are as follows:

`aarondyne_kh2_13thstruggle_or_1250556383.mus` should be renamed to `aarondyne_kh2_13thstruggle_or.mus`

`aarondyne_kh2_darknessofunknow_1250556659.mp3` should be renamed to `aarondyne_kh2_darknessofunknow.mp3`

It seems that some duplicates might exist after I do this, but if the command fails to complete and tells me what the duplicates would be, I can always remove those manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `rename` command. It allows you to rename files based on a regular expression:

The following line should work out for you:

```
rename 's/_\d+(\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+)$/$1/' *
```

The following changes will occur:

```
aarondyne_kh2_13thstruggle_or_1250556383.mus renamed as aarondyne_kh2_13thstruggle_or.mus
aarondyne_kh2_darknessofunknow_1250556659.mp3 renamed as aarondyne_kh2_darknessofunknow.mp3
```

You can check the actions `rename` will do via specifying the `-n` flag, like this:

```
rename -n 's/_\d+(\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+)$/$1/' *
```

For more information on how to use `rename` simply open the manpage via: `man rename`

Comment: Attention: My version of rename (stock fedora 18!) does not have the flag ``-n`` and works different in general. Particularily, it does _not_ support regular expressions, but only globs.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Thanks for the note. I tested the answer on my Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop edition, so it should work out for the initial question at least.

Comment: ... oh, you just delete the digits getting them with `\d+`

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest, but very simple:

```
echo "$filename" | sed -e 's!\(.*\)...........\(\.[^.]*\)!\1\2!'
```

You'll still need to write the rest of the script, but it's pretty simple.

Comment: Interesting. I know  e.g. `sed -e s/anton/berta` to replace `anton` with `berta` using `s` for `substitute`. Your syntax misses forward slashes! And what is `[^.]` for? Is it to exclude all chars?. I know `man sed`..

Comment: ohh, the `!` is now the separator because it is better for filenames, so you search for `...` and replace it with nothing (`\1\2`)?

Comment: plus one for simple design.How do you know to start from the end without the extension?

Comment: I got it man, \1 repeats the first pattern (.*) and \2 the second (file extension after the dot).  Both are loops because of *.The dots are any character, and not visible because they do not appear in the `replace`. I love SO!

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'mv {} `echo -n {} | sed  -E -e "s/[^/]{10}(\\.[^\\.]+)?$/\\1/"`' ";"
```

Comment: I like the short syntax, so plus 1. Can you explain what you did? You replaced all characters, but not the . (`[^\\.]` ) with nothing ( `\\1`)? How does sed know to start from the end but excluding the extension?

Answer (score 0):

one way to go:

you get a list of your files, one per line (by `ls` maybe) then:

```
ls....|awk  '{o=$0;sub(/_[^_.]*\./,".",$0);print "mv "o" "$0}'
```

this will print the `mv a b` command

e.g.

```
kent$  echo "aarondyne_kh2_13thstruggle_or_1250556383.mus"|awk  '{o=$0;sub(/_[^_.]*\./,".",$0);print "mv "o" "$0}'
mv aarondyne_kh2_13thstruggle_or_1250556383.mus aarondyne_kh2_13thstruggle_or.mus
```

to execute, just pipe it to `|sh`

I assume there is no space in your filename.

Comment: There are safer ways of getting the names of all the files than parsing the output of `ls`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

This script assumes each file has just one extension. It would, for instance, rename "foo.something.mus" to "foo.mus". To keep all extensions, remove one hash mark (#) from the first line of the loop body. It also assumes that the base of each filename has at least 12 character, so that removing 11 doesn't leave you with an empty name.

```
for f in *; do
    ext=${f##*.}
    new_f=${base%???????????.$ext}
    if [ -f "$new_f" ]; then
        echo "Will not rename $f, $new_f already exists" >&2
    else
        mv "$f" "$new_f"
    fi
done
```